# Loop Not Running Through Entire Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, loops, recordset

So I have a system built in which it sets a few different flags and so on and so forth, but one of the things I want to do is take the contents of a staging table and send it over to another table used for tracking. I'm trying to do it using an insert into loop but I simply cannot figure out how to make it work as intended.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryDeleteEmail")
    Dim db As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim test As Object

    Set db = Application.CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("qryDate")
    Set test = db.OpenRecordset("tblEmailTemp")

    If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No delinquent accounts. No email will be generated.")
        Me.Refresh
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "qryDate", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
    Else
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst.EOF
           rst.Edit
           rst!NeedsEmail = 1
           rst.Update
           rst.MoveNext
        Loop

        'DoCmd.Requery
        'rst.Close


        DoCmd.RunMacro ("StagingTable")
        test.MoveFirst

        Do Until test.EOF
            CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into EmailTracking (Account, ExpirationDate)" & _
                "Values ('" & AccountName & "', '" & ExpirationDate & "')"
            test.MoveNext              
        Loop

        test.Close
        rst.MoveFirst

        Do Until rst.EOF
            rst.Edit
            rst!EmailSent = 1
            rst.Update
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop

        'DoCmd.Requery
        rst.Close
        DoCmd.RunMacro ("Close")
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryDeleteEmail")
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

What's happening right now is it's copying the first record of the staging table twice. For instance I have an account name A and an account name S, but instead of inserting the record for A and the record for S, it is simply inserting A twice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The indentation of your code doesn't make sense, I edited it. There is still a lot that doesn't make sense in this little portion of code.

Comment: Well, I'll be the first to admit that I'm pretty bad at this and still trying to learn. Appreciate the edit, though. It does make it easier to read.

Comment: What is the macro "StagingTable" doing?  Also, you haven't initialized AccountName and ExpirationDate.  I suggestion placing `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.  What you may wanting to do is `test!AccountName` and `test!ExpirationDate`.

Comment: The stagingtable macro is pulling information to a table for my email module to read. Basically, what's happening is the first loop is flagging entries as needing an email. The stagingtable macro is then pulling flagged entries for my email module. After the macro runs the entries are then flagged as email sent. That part works perfectly.

I'm not 100% sure what you mean when you say initialize and in what context the test!AccountName statements would be used. I'm still learning VBA as a whole so my apologies if I come off like a moron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create and test a simpler procedure which is narrowly focused on the issue you're trying to solve.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what that issue is.  I'll suggest this anyway ...

```
Public Sub TestLoopThruTable()
    Dim db As DAO.database
    Dim test As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strInsert As String

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True ' make sure SetWarnings is on
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set test = db.OpenRecordset("tblEmailTemp")
    Do While Not test.EOF
        strInsert = "INSERT INTO EmailTracking (Account, ExpirationDate)" & vbCrLf & _
            "VALUES ('" & AccountName & "', '" & ExpirationDate & "')"
        Debug.Print strInsert
        'db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
        test.MoveNext
    Loop
    test.Close
    Set test = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Notice in your original version there was no space between `ExpirationDate)` and `Values`.  I used a line break (`vbCrLf`) instead of a space, but either will keep the db engine happy.

I made sure `SetWarnings` is on.  In your code, you turned it off at the start but never turned it back on again.  Operating with `SetWarnings` off suppresses important information which you could otherwise use to understand problems with your code.

As that code loops through the recordset, it simply creates an `INSERT` statement and displays it for each row.  You can view the output in the Immediate window (go there with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> keyboard shortcut).  Copy one of those `INSERT` statements and test by pasting into SQL View of a new Access query.  If it fails there, figure out what you need to change to satisfy the db engine.  If the `INSERT` succeeds, try executing them from your code: enable the `db.Execute` line by removing the single quote from the start of that line.

The way you wrote the `VALUES` clause, it appears `[ExpirationDate]` is a text field.  However if its data type is actually Date/Time, don't include quotes around the value you're inserting; use the `#` date delimiter instead of quotes.

Also make sure to include `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section of your code module like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
```

I mentioned that point because in an earlier version of this question you showed `Option Compare` but not `Option Explicit`.  Trying to troubleshoot code without `Option Explicit` is a waste of time IMO.

Comment: Seems to me that would be better using a QueryDef based on a parameter query.  Then each time thru the loop you could just supply the parameter values and execute the QueryDef.  I ran out of ambition.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'll referring to this as I try to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do here; it is hard to understand what `ErrorHandler` is doing in the `Else` statement (even if commented).

As far as looping through a recordset goes, I advice you to read a little bit about the basis of VBA programmation in MS-Access. You can start by reading the articles below. It is a quick introduction about VBA recordsets and then the most common mistakes in VBA.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-vba-recordset-objects/373

It should help you improving your code.